# how to get maximum volume level in delphi?

Tags: delphi, windows-7, media-player, volume

I try Get and Set the MediaPlayer Sound Volume by 
http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2006/qt/mediaplayer_vol.htm

but 1000 is not full sound volume. how to get Maximum volume level?

Comment: You should add your windows version... (I think this should work with XP)

Comment: And ur windows ??? there is 3 volume levels (or even four): x1 as the player's internals (sound saturation), x2 as your program's volume (Vista+) and x3 as overall volume of WaveOut channel (or how your soundcard drivers would call it) and x4 as master volume of computer.
To maximize their product you'd have to maximize each of coeffs (though it was reported it can damage hardware on some laptops). Also VfW/MCI is **ancient** API - 1993 ! Consider using other music player like BASS library or DSPack

Comment: Btw MSDN states that MCI_DGV_STATUS_VOLUME returns the average of the volume to the left and right speakers (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798405%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MCI interface does not specify a maximum value for the volume.

The `mciSendCommand` API function expects a *factor* for the given parameters. In MCI terms factors are scaled with 1000:

```
 500 = 0.5 // 50%, half the normal value
1000 = 1.0 // 100%, normal value
2000 = 2.0 // 200%, double the normal value
```

(What that factor actually means depends on the specific API function)

In your case 1000 means 100% volume, all smaller values are setting an attenuation. Of course the actual audio driver behind the MCI interface can also accept amplifications, i.e. values > 1000.

Using a value of 1000 as the maximum seems to be a safe choice.

If you are about to create some kind of multimedia application you should seriously consider a more current interface or library. (Personally I've had good experiences with [FMOD](http://www.fmod.org/fmod-downloads.html) and Delphi)